# Rewrite a single URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to reqwrite a URL **www.mysite.com/this/index.php**
to **www.mysite.com**

I knwo it's a bit complex..it tried this code on my root htaccess but it doesn't seem to work
What am i doing wrong here?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.us$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.us$
RewriteRule ^/this/index.php$ /
```

Comment: Try to add a `[R]` to the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

erm, you wish to check against `mysite.us` and have used `mysite.com` in rewrite rule, Ignoring that fact, here is the result I think will work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.(us|com)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.(us|com)$
RewriteRule ^this/index.php$ / [R]
```

Basically, I just removed the `/` character from `^/this` because that's how links are matched.

And the `[R]` means **r** edirect which means it changes the url in your browser. Otherwise you don't see the url is changed, you only see the page is changed.

Here's the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/8e7rq) from [htaccess.madewithlove.be](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).

Comment: @t_virus I think you used the same `%{HTTP_HOST}` condition. here, I edited the post and include a screenshot.